# Calibration measurements using corresponded linear regression coeffients in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, batch-processing

I am currently working on a project involving calibrating sensor measurements to enable comparison between them. For each sensor, I have a set of linear regression coefficients used for calibration purposes.

My data is structured in two separate DataFrame objects. What would be an efficient method to apply these calibrations across all the sensors represented in these DataFrames?

**Table 1**

| Sensor | PM25 |
| --- | --- |
| A01 | 15 |
| A01 | 16 |
| A01 | 15 |
| A01 | 16 |
| A02 | 10 |
| A02 | 9 |
| A02 | 8 |
| A02 | 8 |

**Table 2**

| Sensor | alpha | beta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 0.9 | 10 |
| A02 | 0.8 | 5 |

I want to add a column in Table 1, **PM25_adjusted**, equal to **alpha*****PM25**+**beta** for the corresponding sensor. The data set is very large.